Modify a parameter of a running (or finished) build in TeamCity via REST API
I am trying to modify a parameter (e.g. configuration parameter) of a running (or finished) build named 'lock' and want to insert the value: "true".
My initial thought was to send a rest api call with a service message which sets the parameter.
    response = requests.post(f"{teamcity_build_api_endpoint}/id:{build_id}/log", headers=header_text_plain, data="##teamcity[setParameter name='lock' value='true']")

Even though, this is not throwing any exceptions it also does not modify the parameter.
What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible to alter parameters via rest api?
Background information:
What I need is a shared parameter for a couple of builds which are triggered from an initial one. The triggered builds should report their result into a parameter. For that reason I wanted to introduce a lock mechanism so that only one triggered build can change the parameter at the time.


What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible to alter parameters via rest api?

The ##teamcity[setParameter name='lock' value='true'] service message syntax is intended to be used inside a script running within the build itself which means there is a specific point in time when this change could be applied:

To be processed by TeamCity, they need to be written to the standard output stream of the build, that is printed or echoed from a build step.

I can't imagine how modifying the build parameter via the API would be possible for a running build on a lower level - how would TeamCity decide when exactly it will apply the new value if the build is already running and a certain process is already being executed?
For a build configuration it might be possible but this generally means that you don't have information on what and why has changed the value of the parameter.

What I need is a shared parameter for a couple of builds which are triggered from an initial one. The triggered builds should report their result into a parameter. For that reason I wanted to introduce a lock mechanism so that only one triggered build can change the parameter at the time.

I'm not sure I fully understand your design idea and how it fits into the build chain concept. But in general TeamCity already has a lock mechanism in place - it's the Shared Resources build feature. It seems like it should solve your problem which basically boils down to prohibition of parallel execution of those two build configurations.

The important thing is that I want to report "results" to a finished build into a parameter (not only a lock)  via rest api. That is not possible like described by you. Even though, I found a solution by utilizing attributes instead of parameters. Means, with a rest api call I can see all parameters with /app/rest/builds/id:<build_id_of_finished_build>/attributes and also modify them with ../attributes/<my_attribute> and putting the new value into the body. There are some limitations to that, but for my scenario it worked.
